# Check if cell contain string

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to check if a specific URL contains any string from date base.
Here You got a screenshot with an explanation.

[image: Check if cell contain specific string]

Link to the example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16dvAx_MCycICUqsNXjHieeIPE80wHH5brq8qcDVQjJ8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(B2:B23, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, D2:D23))*1)
```

[image]